# How to add an ID / name to a component to show in browser dev mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am new to web dev and I have a basic question:

In browser dev mode I can 'inspect' the selected UI component in the structure of the page:

Chrome developer mode ---> Elements ---> structure tree of the page;

[image]

I can see all these  components but it is very hard to know which ReactJS component it corresponds to.

Is there a way that I can add an ID /name to the ReactJS component such that it shows up in the developer tool?

For example, the highlighted line is: `<div class="MuiBox-root" css-1n8fc9c>`

What is this mysterious ID "css-1n8fc9c"?

Comment: You cannot do such an action but you can highlight over the element and check where that div lies in your component tree

Comment: I see that you have React Developer Tools installed, you can access it through the "Components" tab, there you can inspect components